# Array to Json with multiple same keys

Tags: php

I have this simple array with 2 elements which is being converted into json format:

```
echo '['.json_encode(array("name" => "FRENCH POLYNESIA", "name" => "POLAND")).']';
```

The result is: `[{"name":"POLAND"}]`

In my case I need this result: `[{"name": "FRENCH POLYNESIA"},{"name": "POLAND"}]` How I can do this ?

Comment: You can't create two keys in the same array, the last one will overwrite the previous values.

Comment: echo json_encode([array("name" => "FRENCH POLYNESIA"), array("name" => "Poland")]);

Comment: even without `json_decode` you will not be able to initialize array with key duplicated. so change/fix array initialization up to your needs

Comment: I mean you can't create two identical* keys.

Answer (score 3):

This JSON:

```
[{"name": "FRENCH POLYNESIA"},{"name": "POLAND"}]
```

is an array containing two objects. So you need your input array to contain two *arrays* rather than two key-value pairs.

```
array(array("name" => "FRENCH POLYNESIA"), array("name" => "POLAND"))
```

`json_encode` will convert the inner arrays to objects.

It's already been mentioned in the comments, but your original array format doesn't make sense because you can't have two of the same array key anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create two (or more) identical keys in the same array, the last value will overwrite the previous ones.

This value:

```
[{"name": "FRENCH POLYNESIA"},{"name": "POLAND"}]
```

Is decoded to

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'FRENCH POLYNESIA' (length=16)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'POLAND' (length=6)
```

So to answer your question, your array should look like this

```
$array = [
    array(
       'name' => 'FRENCH POLYNESIA'
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'POLAND'
    ),
];
```

Comment: _"You can't create two keys in the same array."_ Missing probably a word, right?

Comment: @Syscall Yes, I fixed it. Thanks!